SwiftUI .onAppear and ViewModifier (Progress) procedure. Why it is important?
I've make a custom ViewModifier like "Progress bar" (but in code below, for example, I use just different background color.
I have a function to download data from API (in code below, for example, I use 'fake' download with 3 sec delay.
I use Boolean variable to check ifLoading.
And my question is, why if I write
.progress
.onAppear {download function}
all is OK, but if I change order to
.onAppear {download function}
.progress
it will be endless 'Progress' and my main View will never shown.
I need to understand why its happened, and why all is ok in other order.
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isLoaded = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            Text("Example")
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .font(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.title/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .bold()
        }
        .onAppear { fakeNetworkCall() }
        .progress(isLoaded: isLoaded)
    }

    
    func fakeNetworkCall() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3 ) {
            isLoaded = false
        }
    }
}


struct LoadingView: ViewModifier {
    var isLoaded : Bool
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if isLoaded {
            ZStack {
                Color.red
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                Text("Example")
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .font(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.title/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .bold()
            }
        } else {
          content
        }
    }
}


extension View {
    func progress(isLoaded: Bool) -> some View {
        modifier(LoadingView(isLoaded: isLoaded))
    }
}

as I sad, if I will change to
        .progress(isLoaded: isLoaded)
        .onAppear { fakeNetworkCall() }

all is OK, but I Don't understand why.

you can't use DispatchQueue inside of a struct because it has no lifetime so the callback is on something that no longer exists, i.e. it isn't possible for the async closure to retain self like it could if it was in an object because self is just a value like an int.

@malhal This is wrong. The struct value will be copied to the heap for the closure. It's also possible to mutate the state property in the closure - which would not be possible with normal properties, since self is not mutable. It works with @State, because it's a property wrapper and actually is a reference to the storage managed by SwiftUI under the hood. It should even work when the underlying view disappeared - simply due to the closure holding a reference to the storage. What the change to the storage means when there is no associated view, is undefined. Very likely, it has no effect.

Imagine "inlining" the view modifier and it becomes very clear. In other words, replace content in the view modifier's body with the actual view that it is modifying:
if isLoaded {
    ZStack {
        Color.red
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        Text("Example")
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .font(.title)
            .bold()
    }
} else {
    ZStack {
        Color.blue
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        Text("Example")
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .font(.title)
            .bold()
    }
    .onAppear { fakeNetworkCall() }
}

The onAppear modifier modifies the ZStack in the else branch. Since the if statement is initially true, the view in else never appears, so onAppear never gets called.
If you place progress before onAppear, onAppear modifies the whole if...else statement (aka _ConditionalContent) that is the body of the view modifier. This view always appears.
Kind of like this
Group {
    if isLoaded {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            Text("Example")
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
        }
    } else {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            Text("Example")
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
        }
    }
}
.onAppear { fakeNetworkCall() }


so if I understand You correctly,
if .progress goes after .onAppear, it will be the first part of Your answer (The onAppear modifier modifies the ZStack in the else branch. Since the if statement is initially true, the view in else never appears, so onAppear never gets called.), but if .progress will be BEFORE .onAppear - .onAppear will modifies all stack(if and else) and all is ok?
than another 1 question, could You please write me in what order all elements will be called in 1 and 2nd variants?
Thanks!

@Anton Your understanding is correct. I didn't quite understand what your additional question is. What does it mean for an "element" tp get "called"?

I mean all 'stages' of building of my code: in what order each element goes (to understand why .onAppear .progress don't take first part to the code)

@Anton sorry, I still don’t understand. Every modifier is applied from top to bottom, and modified everything before it. progress creates a view that you wrote in LoadingView, replacing content with whatever it modifies. If you are still confused, I suggest posting a new question and explain exactly what you don’t understand.
